# Magento problem- The admin page is not loading correctly

Tags: magento

I am trying to load my admin page but it loads to a ceratin percentage and then freezes. Here is my screenshot:
[image]

I tried to increase the memmory limit and max execution time in php.ini, made 'clear:cache' and flush command but with no result.

Comment: try to look network tab of developer tool

Comment: I actually changed to developer mode but still no result.

Comment: try bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <languages> in dev mode

Comment: Can you find any info in browser console and network tab?
DId you check the logs. can you also provide the log info if any?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?